# Web app that can post on both Facebook pages and WordPress.com blog?

Tags: web-apps, wordpress, facebook

I am looking for an app that can:

1. Post to Facebook pages.
2. Post to wordpress.com blogs.

That is, I will write a post on the app and it will post behalf of me on the two platforms mentioned above.

I know [Buffer](https://buffer.com/), but it can't post to wordpress.com blogs.

I would prefer a free app or services that offer a free plan.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth taking a look at https://zapier.com/ They have various tools that connect different systems to automate things like this.

Personally I make a post directly on wordpress and then use either zapier to pull the rss feed and push it to Buffer which then pushes it out to the connected social networks or just use Hootsuite which will read the wordpress rss feed directly and push it out without the need for zapier.

Answer (score 0):

My team use and trust [hootsuite](https://www.hootsuite.com/).
There is a plugin for wordpress also [wp-hootsuite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-to-hootsuite/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).